# How to get child div contents from multiple parent divs with same id when each of them is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have multiple divs with same id , i need to get the content of child's div when the parent div is clicked, the divs are dynamically created. The following code explains that :

i have php file that generate the multiple divs with the same id as follows :

```
<div id="display" style="display: block;">
<div class="display_box" id="display_box" align="left">
<div class="pic"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/picture"></div>
<div class="picName">Sahrish Rizwan</div>
</div>
 <div class="display_box" id="display_box" align="left">
<div class="pic"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/picture"></div>           
<div class="picName">Sahil Devji</div>
</div>
<div class="display_box" id="display_box" align="left">
<div class="pic"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/picture"></div>
<div class="picName">Sahar Imtiaz</div>
</div>
<div class="display_box" id="display_box" align="left">
<div class="pic"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/picture"></div>
<div class="picName">Sahil Devji</div>
</div>
</div>
```

now i need to get the content of each display_box through jquery , can any one help me out this ?

Comment: Bad practice to have multiple elements with same `id`. Use classes.

Comment: as they are generated dynamically and there is no fixed number of divs that are generated so i can't use different ids for each

Comment: You can always use different `id`s for each. Just append a value 1,2...n so on to the `id` when they are being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (see fiddle console)

```
$(document).on('click','#display',function(){
    $(this).find('.display_box').each(function(){
       console.log($(this).html()) // returns overall content 
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/5/)

OR

```
$(document).on('click','.display_box',function(){
   console.log($(this).html()) // returns clicked content 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aBEf/5/)

Comment: it gives content of each display_box , i just want the content of the div that is clicked

Comment: @user3572213 i will updaed this in answer upvoted it

Comment: can you tell me now how to close the display div when users clicked any of the display_box ?

Comment: close means you want to hide display div when display_box clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.display_box',function(){
   alert($(this).html()) 
});
```